# Retrofit returns 200 and starts next activity even when input is wrong

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit

I am using retrofit to authenticate user but when wrong input is entered, response code is 200 and the next activity starts.

```
public void serverLogin(){
    //                         Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface
    apiInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);
    UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
    userModel.setUsername(username);
    userModel.setPassword(password);

    Call<IDModel> activate = apiInterface.userLogin(userModel);
    activate.enqueue(new Callback<IDModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<IDModel> call, Response<IDModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                response.body();

                customerID = response.body().getCustomer_id();
                subID = response.body().getSub_id();
                idDB.addCustomerID(customerID, subID);

                session.setLoggedIn(true);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Drawer.class);
                intent.putExtra("cusID", customerID);
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("onresponse", "" + statusCode);

            }
            else  {
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<IDModel> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("onfailure"," " +  t . getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

The else part always gets skipped. When it is not successful, I want to notify the user and not start next activity.

Comment: Do you think the server should respond with some other status code than "200"? Then it looks like the server code needs fixing.

Comment: The response code is based on the server's http return, not retrofit.

Comment: I am using php for server side. Can i see an example of how it should look like?

Comment: `response.isSuccessful()` will always return true, if your app can connect to server and server responds, even if it is a 404.

Comment: I returned the error response code from server side and it works. Thanks

Comment: Actually, `response.isSuccessful()` returns true only for success status codes, that is codes within [200:300[. At least it's documented like that and to me makes more sense. I agree that if you think the status should not be successful, then you'd need to change the server code.